# Get account by user id

Tags: account, relationships, user

I need select account by id. I do:

```
List<User> u = [SELECT Name, Contact.Account.Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    System.debug('accId = ' + u[0].Contact.Account.Id);
if(!u.isEmpty()) {
   Id accountId = u[0].Contact.Account.Id;
   //But accountId is null ((((
}
```

But the accountId is null...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) object fields in SFDC ,AccountId and ContactId fields are populated only if your user is a portal/community user

Also you can directly use the AccountId field instead of using the relationship query here

```
List<User> u = [SELECT Name, AccountId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
System.debug('accId = ' + u[0].AccountId);
if(!u.isEmpty()) {
   Id accountId = u[0].AccountId;
   //AccountId is populated if you run this as a community user /portal users .For admin Users this value is null ((((
}
```